# Google emulator displays mobile site great but when actually on site it does not work. What can I do to figure out what is broken?

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, emulation

I am trying to figure out the problem that I am having with the website I am creating.

It is a fairly simple website so I have been using flexbox for most of the layout. When I emulate it in Chrome for an iPhone6 or other mobile device the content is all there but when I actually open it on my device on the staging site it disappears. Not sure what is going on.

I am not a very experienced coder and am putting this website together for my dad as a favour for putting me through design school. As a result, some of my code is probably super janky and not the proper way. I was wondering if someone knew what was going on and could point me in the right direction.

The staging site can be viewed at [fairfieldtreenurseries.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0x5L.jpg)

Example picture:

[Imagery of Differences between emulator and live site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0x5L.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide code so that we can dig into it. A JSFiddle or staging URL.

Comment: There is a URL in the post. Does that work or should I do something else?

Comment: The question should contain a minimal working code snippet within itself, reproducing the issue, not as an external link, and the reason is, when that link dies, so does the value of this question and its answers. Read more here how to ask questions properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay, I will take a look at doing that later. I am just not sure where the problem is and don't know what snippet to upload but I will try and figure something out.